# Disable all Validator controls on a page

Tags: asp.net, validation

During the early stages of a dev cycle, it's a bit annoying to have all the validation controls enforcing their rules if we just want to move quickly from form to form.

What is the simplest way to disable all the validator controls on a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a javascript to get all the validator controls in your page and set their value to false in a for loop, something like this would work

```
function DisablePageValidators()
{   
 if ((typeof(Page_Validators) != "undefined") && (Page_Validators != null)) 
  {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i], false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've done something seriously wrong if you don't validate server side too!

Comment: validate server side too? this person is trying to disable validation, so this method I posted would disable all the validation within the page

Comment: Looking for a way to shut it all off--server side and client side.

Comment: Yes- so you are saying you don't check if the page is valid on the server side? You don't use this- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx

Comment: @RichardOD-Im not understanding what you're disagreeing with, you just posted the same answer I have to my understanding

Comment: Server side validation can (and should) still take place even when Javascript is disabled. This doesn't prevent server-side validation and hence doesn't properly address the problem and really shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: This fixed a problem I encountered in one of my projects, but I agree with RichardOD : you've done something seriously wrong if you don't validate server side too. In my case, the validators should not even be triggered on this event. I should rewire the whole page, but I have been given 3 hours in total to fix this project, so I take shortcuts. Thank you for this shortcut!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

Page_ValidationActive = false;

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to [recursively loop through all controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/eporter/archive/2007/02/24/asp-net-findcontrol-recursive-with-generics.aspx) on the page, looking for all  controls that inherit from the [BaseValidator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx), and then set their `Enabled` property to `False`. You could write this as a simple library method.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works fine for me.

```
foreach (BaseValidator vValidator in Page.Validators)
{
    vValidator.EnableClientScript = false;
    vValidator.Enabled = false;
}
```

Thx.=> https://forums.asp.net/post/1446219.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to input garbage data, might it be easier to put in a quick hack to let you just skip forward to the page you wanted to be on in the first place, instead of fiddling with validation?

Comment: Maybe so.  I was hoping there's just an easy way to "fiddle" with the validation and turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Remove them from the page.