# How to disable asp.net validator on client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have very simple aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="tbText" ValidationGroup="Address"></asp:textbox>
        <br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvText" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbText" 
            ValidationGroup="Address" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">Enter text</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="Submit_Click" 
            ValidationGroup="Address" OnClientClick="DisableValidator();" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function DisableValidator() {
                alert('Called and disable validators before submit');

                var validator = document.getElementById("<%=rfvText.ClientID%>");
                validator.validationGroup = "someGroup";
                ValidatorEnable(validator, false);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate("Address");
        if (!IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Page is no valid");
        }
    }
}
```

All elements on the page have ValidationGroup="Address", but I need disable my validator just before I click on the button. So, on client site it disables, but when I try to validate it on the server, my page isn't valid on the server but valid on client.

How can I disable validator on client to became disable on the server also?

Thanks!

Comment: Below solution works fine for me. [My response from other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67934225/833409)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to programmably disable it when the page posts back, however you interpret that validator should be disabled on the client then would need to be replicated on the server, and set `Enabled="false"`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `EnableClientScript="False"` on **the validation control**, that is:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvText" 
      runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbText"
      ValidationGroup="Address" 
      EnableClientScript="False"
      ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">Enter Text
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4, try using the `EnableClientScript` property. I've never used it myself but according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx), it should meet your needs.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether client-side validation is enabled.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" EnableClientScript="False" />
```

Comment: What version .NET are you running?

Comment: Doh. That property is new to .NET 4.