# Doing clientside validation based on the value of a hidden variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have an asp.net web application where if the user selected option "A", I display a popup window where the user enters Date, First Name, Last Name etc and there are validation controls to do clientside validation.

However, if a user selects option "B", they just fill a comments section and submit the page.

The issue I am having is that since its the same aspx page, the validation controls won't allow the form to be submiited if the user selects option "B". So I created a hidden variable to store a value if the user selects option "A".

My question is how can I disable clientside validation if user selects option "B" ?

I found this post ([How to disable asp.net validator on client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11672388/72324)), however, this mentions of a postback (which I want to avoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479045#aspplusvalid_clientside) the client-side API. Either Page_ValidationActive or the ValidatorEnable functions can be a solution for your problem.